# $A$ not Lebesgue-measurable in $\Bbb{R} \implies A \times \Bbb{R}$ is not Lebesgue-measurable in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How do I show that if $A$ is not Lebesgue-measurable in $\Bbb{R}$ then $A \times \Bbb{R}$ is not Lebesgue-measurable in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Have you tried to apply Fubini's theorem for complete measures?

Comment: You are right! Tonelli's theorem shows it immediately. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For any set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, you can define a section of $E$ as
$$
E_y := \{x \in \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \in E\}
$$
Similarly define $E^x$, and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the collection of all subsets $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $E_y$ and $E^x$ are both measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now prove that this collection $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains all rectangles. Hence, $\mathcal{M}$ must contain all measurable subsets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In particular, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is such that $E := A\times \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then
$$
A = E_0
$$
must be measurable in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is  $\sigma$-algebra which contains all the measurable subsets of $\Bbb R$ as well.

Comment: If I understand your proof correctly, it proves it only for Borel measurable sets, isn't it?